# Pausing or aborting movement to a goal

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the best way to programatically pause or abort movement towards a goal location once it's in the process of being executed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9684/pausing-or-aborting-movement-to-a-goal/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-04-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The move_base node uses an action interface for managing its goals which is built on top of ROS topics one of which is, in this case, move_base/cancel. You can send a message-based cancel request, but I'd recommend using an action client to interact with move_base. Documentation that will probably be useful includes, actionlib documentation (http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib), and a tutorial on sending goals to the navigation stack using actionlib (http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2016-06-27**:
Is it possible to cancel the goal inside the `ActionServer` itself without adding a client side to it. I'm adding priorities to my multiple action servers and whenever any of the callbacks is triggered the server has to check if a goal with a higher priority is currently being executed.

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2016-06-27**:
If the received goal is with a higher priority of the currently running goal, the currently running goal needs to be canceled and the new goal is executed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The action client also defines methods for canceling a goal which just sends a preemption request to the action server. If implemented correctly, the server then stops executing the goal as soon as possible. The method for canceling the goal in SimpleActionServer is cancelGoal.

There is no way to pause an action. You always need to cancel it and re-send the goal when you want to continue.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-04-11**:
There is a topic called /move_base/cancel.  If this is what I should be publishing to what type of messages should I be sending?